# How to prevent created elements from disappearing when Refreshing (F5)

Tags: javascript

I want to prevent created elements from disappearing when refreshing(F5)

```
var newdiv= document.createElement("DIV");

document.getElementById('ForPendingReservation').prepend(newdiv);
var att = document.createAttribute("id");
att.value = "pendingbox";
newdiv.setAttributeNode(att);
```

[created Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKkiQ.png)

[when refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlm68.png)

Comment: By using localstorage and preload depending on the value?

Comment: you can use browser's `localStorage`

Answer (score 0):

you can use localStorage to set items and get items after refresh

Save Items

```
var listItems = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4'];
window.localStorage.setItem('listItems', JSON.stringify(listItems));
```

and on load the page

```
var listItems = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('listItems'));
if(listItems) {
    for(var i in listItems) {
        // addItem(listItems[i]);
    }
}
```